# Why can't I import AAC files downloaded with youtube-dl into iTunes?

Tags: itunes, audio, windows, youtube

When I download a song with youtube-dl into AAC, then I cannot import it into iTunes. iTunes doesn't give an error. It just ignores it.

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format aac https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123 --verbose

[download] 100% of 5.88MiB in 00:03
[debug] ffmpeg command line: ffprobe -show_streams "file:xxxxxx.webm"
[ffmpeg] Destination: xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.aac
[debug] ffmpeg command line: ffmpeg -y -loglevel "repeat+info" -i "file:xxxxxxxxxxxx.webm" -vn -acodec aac "-q:a" 5 -f adts "file:xxxxxxxx.aac"
Deleting original file xxxxxxxxxxxx.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

---

```
ffprobe xxxxxxxxxxxx.aac

[aac @ 0000006501ace3c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, aac, from 'xxxxxxxxx.aac':
  Duration: 00:12:39.84, bitrate: 249 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 249 kb/s
```

It works with m4a.

iTunes Version 12.9.4.102

---

@nohillside Yes it happens with all AAC files I try to download with youtuble-dl. Yes it does work if I use mp3 also. Yes I am using Windows.

@slm I don't have any original AAC files to test with. All AAC files have been generated with ffmpeg/youtube-dl. I found this sample AAC file from http://samplephotovideo.com/2015/12/download-aac-mpeg-2-advanced-audio-coding-file/, http://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/example.aac, and was unable to import it into iTunes. Drag & Drop shows a red-circle-crossed and File > Add File to Library just ignores it.

Comment: Does this happen with all AAC files or only with that one? Does it work if you convert to MP3 instead?

Comment: Ah, and are you using Windows (as you tagged the question as such)?

Comment: I would confirm that you can take a downloaded WEBM and use the `ffmpeg` command that `youtube-dl` is showing and manually run that and verify the result w/ other known AAC files you know can be imported.

Comment: This is because iTunes assumes that AAC is encapsulated inside a MPEG-4 bytestream (M4A in the case of iTunes). As iTunes might be unable to decode raw ADTS files so you're unable to import it.